# For Kubernetes pods how to find cause of exit code 2

Tags: docker, kubernetes

I have pods that are of kind `Cronjob` running in parallel. They complete their task and run again after a fixed interval of 20 minutes as per the cron expression. I noticed that some pods are restarting 2-3 times before completing their task.

I checked for details with the `kubectl describe pod` command and found that the pods terminate with `exit code 2` when it restart due to some error:

```
Last State:     Terminated
      Reason:       Error
      Exit Code:    2
```

I searched about exit code 2 and found that it is misuse of a `shell builtin commands`. How I can find which shell builtin is misused? How to debug the cause of exit code 2?

Comment: This is incredibly dependent on the code running inside the pod.  There's nothing that special about the number 2 that would point at a single definite cause.  Can you [edit] the question to include a [mcve]?

Comment: I found issue was with code after carefully going though code and application logs. There was null check that was causing this issue. Thanks for providing direction.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

An exit code of 2 indicates either that the application chose to return that error code, or (by convention) there was a misuse of a shell built-in. Check your pod’s command specification to ensure that the command is correct. If you think it is correct, try running the image locally with a shell and run the command directly.

Refer to this [link](https://www.datree.io/resources/kubernetes-error-codes-crashloopbackoff) for more information.

Answer (score 0):

You can get logs with

```
kubectl logs my-pod
```

Post output here if you can't fix it.

Comment: Thanks for reply. I have already check logs from kubectl logs. It only show application logs and nothing unusal in logs.

Comment: What's your output for kubectl get pods ?

Comment: Also, did you check this one? https://containersolutions.github.io/runbooks/posts/kubernetes/crashloopbackoff/